# Matplotlib giving the wrong plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I made a linear regression model and I want to plot the predicted results against the actual ones, so I wrote the following:

```
x = df['Years of Experience'].values
y = df['Salary'].values
for i in range(len(x)): #had a type error so did this
    x[i]=float(x[i])
beta1=regressor.coef_[0]
beta0=regressor.intercept_[0]
ypred = beta1*x + beta0
plt.plot(x,y,'o')                   
plt.plot(x,ypred,'-',linewidth=3) 
plt.xlabel('Years of Experience')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
```

I imported the following libraries:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib
%matplotlib inline
```

I made sure that all variables (beta and ypred) have values as expected but there seems to be something wrong with the plot as it gave the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like a matter of Y-axis range ..

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x,y,'o')                   
ax2.plot(x,ypred,'-',linewidth=3) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: This just makes it _look_ like the results are the same.  It doesn't solve the original problem which is that the prediction is not scaled properly to the data.